# Folder set-up automation Photoshop actions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, actions, comics

My goal is to create an action that sets up a folder structure for a comic panel as the image below suggests.

[image: example]

My attempt ended up with this result.

[image: Result]

The main issue is that the color-coded folders aren't nested inside of the `panel_00`folder.
I've attempted to switch around the order of which folder gets created first, but I always seem to get this result. It is my first dive into automating actions with Photoshop so I would appreciate any insight.

Also is there a way to have the `panel_00` folder dynamically update its count depending on how many of them I make? or would that be dipping into scripting territory?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried Recording an Action while selecting all three folders and their content layers, and then hit Ctrl+G (Group)? That should make a group containing the others. as sub groups. I just tried it. Seems to work in an Action.

Comment: Just off the top of my head...  Select > All Layers, Group, rename group. The select all layers will retain the groups. The only problem would be if you have *other* layers you *don't* want in the master group.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked; the only issue was that if I used Select All Layers, the latest panel group would nest the previous ones rather than them staying individual groups, this would have gotten rather confusing to navigate, the work around I found was individually selecting the folders instead. So, that it only targeted them in the selection.

Comment: Update: upon further testing there still seems to be clashing when I run the action multiple times. It ends up targeting some of the folders/layers for the previous ones, but instead of everything it's the drawing folders.